# Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: magento2, php-7.4

Trying to access array offset on value of type null on Instagramshoppable/Controller/Gallery/Popuphtml.php on line 58

$a1 = file_get_contents($insta_url);
$b1 = json_decode($a1, TRUE);

```
            $instaArr=$b1['graphql']['shortcode_media'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may occur if $b1 have some data but doesn't have index['graphql']['shortcode_media'];

So first check if the index exist then assign it to some variable your's code should be like

```
if(isset($b1['graphql']['shortcode_media'])) { $instaArr=$b1['graphql']['shortcode_media']; }
```